# SetState not updating the value in react js functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

in a functional component i need to show the message to user that email is being sent
i am changing the html element text by set state

here is the code

```
const [visibility, setVisibility] = useState("hidden");
const [MessageText, setMessageText] = useState("");



 function sendEmail()
    {
    setVisibility('visible');
    setMessageText("Sending email to the recipients.Please wait...");
     functionToSendEmail();
    }


    <label className="cs-label" id="lblMessage" 
style={{ color: '#800000', fontWeight: 'bold', visibility: visibility }}> {MessageText} </label>
```

here message is not showing in the `label`  element but if instead of `setMessageText` if i use

```
document.getElementById('lblMessage').innerHTML = "Email sent to the recipients successfully";
```

then its working fine showing message to user

Answer (score 1):

On this code you posted, you're not calling sendEmail() function anywhere. You may call it, then it will call setMessageText().

Try something like this:

```
<button onClick={() => sendEmail()}>Send email</button>
```